# Varnish send while cache

Tags: varnish

I wanted the varnish download the file to the cache while sends to client. From what I am seeing, it first download and then send the file, and that with very large files, is slow.

(sorry for english, I'm using an online translator.)

Answer (score 1):

This is still not supported.  The latest version 2.1.2 will receive the whole response from the backend before sending it to the client.

I hear it's coming soon though.  Keep an eye on the varnish-cache.org news section or perhaps ask in #varnish @ irc.linpro.no.

Comment: is there a specific function name I can look for?